# Deleting and copying array elements in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, material-ui

I have been tasked to add a copy and delete button on one of our tables. I am trying to pass the index from the map to the delete and copy onclick and this does delete but...

Problem: If you copy a row it will have the exact same "i" as the original, and it moves the position of all the ones below it messing up the delete tremendously

I was under the impression that if I setRows() to something new it would run the mapping again and give them all the correct i's in each function but this doesn't seem to be the case, why?

```
const AdvancedTable = () => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState(tableRows); ///tableRows is basically an array of divs
    const deleteOnClick = (i: number) => {
        setRows(() => {
            const myRows = [...rows];
            myRows.splice(i, 1);
            return myRows;
        });
    }
    const copyOnClick = (i: number) => {
        setRows(() => {
            const myRows = [...rows];
            myRows.splice(i, 0, rows[i]);
            return myRows;
        });
    }
    return (

            <Paper>
                     {
                         rows.map((row: any, i: number) => (
                                     <div>
                                         <IconButton onClick={() => { deleteOnClick(i) }} size="small">
                                             <ClearIcon />
                                         </IconButton>
                                         <IconButton onClick={() => { copyOnClick(i) }} size="small">
                                             <FileCopyIcon />
                                         </IconButton>
                                     </div>
                                 </TableCell>
                                 {row}

                         ))}
            </Paper>
    );
}
export default AdvancedTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the copy method to copy the row below the one you clicked or to send it to then end of the array?

maybe this can help you assuming you can call the i value from your row object with .i

```
const copyOnClick = (i: number) => {
    setRows(() => {
        const myRows = [...rows];
        // send the new row to the end of the array
        myRows.splice(rows.length, 0, rows[i]);
        // change the new row i value to + 1 of the last object that was previously in the array
        myRows[myRows.pop().i].i = rows.pop().i + 1
        return myRows;
    });
}
```